# How to display collection field in twig template Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

My Actual Entities Purchase and PO

Purchase Has fields

- Company - Is Seperate Entity in itself
- Product - Is Seperate Entity in itself
- Size - Is Seperate Entity in itself
- Color - Is Seperate Entity in itself
- Cost
- Contact - - Is Seperate Entity in itself

PO [Purchase Order] Has some fields plus a collection field of Purchase. How Do I display fields of Collection Entity -- Purchase.

Comment: Is this for a form (i.e. an 'edit' or 'new' action), or a show action?

Comment: @Sean this is not for a form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To print out all of the tag names in a twig template you can use something like the following code.

```
{% for tag in task.tags %}
     {{ tag.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

With whatever styling you want. I think this is what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Can you provide your current twig template?

Comment: I made an error in entity because of which it was not saving the collection